# Cannot export after upgrade to 6.3 / dynamicreports 4.1.1 (from 5.5 / 3.1.5)

Tags: java, jasper-reports, dynamic-reports

I am updating jasperreports and dynamicreports on my server (linux) from 5.5 to 6.3 and from 3.1.5 to 4.1.1.

The sample script (further below) runs fine on my old configuration, but produces following errors after the update: ...seems there is something wrong with the exporting...

```
starting export! 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.setExporterOutput(Lnet/sf/jasperreports/export/ExporterOutput;)V 
at net.sf.dynamicreports.jasper.transformation.ExporterTransform.pdf(ExporterTransform.java:459)
at net.sf.dynamicreports.jasper.transformation.ExporterTransform.transform(ExporterTransform.java:133)
at net.sf.dynamicreports.jasper.builder.JasperReportBuilder.export(JasperReportBuilder.java:633)
at net.sf.dynamicreports.jasper.builder.JasperReportBuilder.toPdf(JasperReportBuilder.java:537) 
 at net.sf.dynamicreports.jasper.builder.JasperReportBuilder.toPdf(JasperReportBuilder.java:533)  
at dynamicreports.Rep3.main(Rep3.java:18)
```

My sample script:

```
package dynamicreports;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import net.sf.dynamicreports.jasper.builder.*;
import net.sf.dynamicreports.report.builder.DynamicReports;
import net.sf.dynamicreports.report.exception.DRException;
public class Rep3 {    

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, DRException {

         System.out.println("starting export!");    
        JasperReportBuilder report=DynamicReports.report();
        report.toPdf(new  FileOutputStream(new File("/tmp/_report.pdf")));
        System.out.println("done!");    
    }    
}
```

I have (as per http://dynamicreports.org/requirements) included all required jars, i am echoing my classpath and checked every single one, maybe I am missing a .jar?

Here is my classpath:

> .:/opt/dlins/jasperreports-6.3.0/build/classes:/u00/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/jdbc/lib/ojdbc6.jar:/u00/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/jlib/orai18n.jar:.0.jar:/opt/dlins/dynamicreports-4.1.1/lib/commons-beanutils-1.9.0.jar:/opt/dlins/dynamicreports-4.1.1/lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar:/opt/dlins/dynamicreports-4.1.1/lib/commons-collections-3.2.2.jar:/opt/dlins/dynamicreports-4.1.1/lib/commons-digester-2.1.jar:/opt/dlins/dynamicreports-4.1.1/lib/commons-codec-1.5.jar:/opt/dlins/dynamicreports-4.1.1/lib/xml-apis-1.3.04.jar:/opt/dlins/dynamicreports-4.1.1/lib/xml-apis-ext-1.3.04.jar:/opt/dlins/dynamicreports-4.1.1/lib/ecj-4.3.1.jar:/opt/dlins/dynamicreports-4.1.1/lib/jfreechart-1.0.19.jar:/opt/dlins/dynamicreports-4.1.1/lib/jcommon-1.0.23.jar:/opt/dlins/dynamicreports-4.1.1/lib/commons-lang3-3.1.jar:/opt/dlins/dynamicreports-4.1.1/lib/jackson-core-2.1.4.jar:/opt/dlins/dynamicreports-4.1.1/lib/jackson-databind-2.1.4.jar:/opt/dlins/dynamicreports-4.1.1/lib/jackson-annotations-2.1.4.jar:/opt/dlins/dynamicreports-4.1.1/lib/log4j-1.2.14.jar:/opt/dlins/dynamicreports-4.1.1/lib/velocity-1.7.jar:/opt/dlins/dynamicreports-4.1.1/lib/itext-2.1.7.js5.jar:/opt/dlins/jasperreports-6.3.0/dist/jasperreports-6.3.0.jar:/opt/dlins/jasperreports-6.3.0/dist/jasperreports-fonts-6.3.0.jar:/opt/dlins/jasperreports-6.3.0/dist/jasperreports-javaflow-6.3.0.jar:/opt/dlins/DynamicJasper-5.0.4/DynamicJasper-5.0.4.jar:/opt/dlins/dynamicreports-4.1.1/dist/dynamicreports-core-4.1.1.jar:/opt/dlins/dynamicreports-4.1.1/dist/dynamicreports-adhoc-4.1.1.jar:/opt/dlins/jar/pdfbox-app-1.8.0.jar:/opt/dlins/jar/batik-all-1.8pre-r1084380.jar:/opt/dlins/jar/json-simple-1.1.1.jar

Comment: Could you do System.out.println(net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperReport.class.getPackage().getImplementationVersion()); in your main to confirm the JasperReports version?

Comment: g‌​etImplementationVers‌​ion() is unknown...

Comment: In that case try   System.out.println(Rep3.class.getResource("/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/export/JRPdfExporter.class"));

Comment: It's null. I have "downgraded" to jasperreports 6.2.2 (as listed as requirement of dynamicreports) and this (now have others) error goes away. consider this solved, thanks for your help